# I have 2 buffers. 1 for Y and 1 for UV in one C file. How I want to combine that functions into one YUV buffer?

Tags: c, buffer, yuv

I have 2 buffers. 1 is Y buffer and 1 is UV buffer in one C file as char array. How can I combine that buffers into one and generate one YUV buffer and after that I want to generate yuv file from that C file? I want to generate image in yuv420p format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not display any effort from OP's side till time. [On-topic Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this should be as simple as a memcpy or two.  yuv420p is a giant array of all 'Y' values, followed by all 'u' values, then all 'v' values.   e.g. for a 4x4 image:  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyuuuuvvvv.